# Difference between "implementing" and "executing" in this context?

Tags: differences, vocabulary

I would appreciate it if you could explain to me the difference between ***implementing*** and ***executing*** in the context of the following sentence:

> The implementing agency(ies) for this project is UNEP and the national executing agency is the Department of Environment.

Comment: @Josh61 check this out:
The implementing agency(ies) for this project is UNEP and the national executing agency is
the Department of Environment

Comment: That example sounds like contracting language, so the rules of "everyday English" may not apply. In other words, two words can be used interchangeably in day-to-day conversation, but have very specific meanings in a more specialized or formal context, as in the [differences](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+verification+and+validation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) between the synonyms [_verify_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verify) and [_validate_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/validate).

Comment: @J.R.: I agree, I don't think this question warrants a hold. The meanings seem to be very specific (as per the comment that I'm about to add under Mathias' answer) and don't seem to be ones that can be found by just consulting a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

According to Dictionary.com, **implement** means *to put into effect according to or by means of a definite plan or procedure.* So basically, *implement* means to begin, to put into action, to set on, to start a course of action.

According to the same source, **execute** means *to perform or accomplish something, as an assigned task.* So the word *execute* means to see through to completion.

In your situation, the UNEP agency would be the agency responsible for starting projects while the Department of Environment agency would be the agency responsible for completing projects.

Comment: +1; I think Mathias is very much on the right track. A link which describes some of the work of the United Nations Environment Program is of interest: http://www.multilateralfund.org/aboutMLF/Implementingagencies/default.aspx "UNEP’s Division of Technology, Industry and Economics ... carries out no investment projects, but rather helps to establish the infrastructure within which projects can proceed. (eg) helping to prepare country programmes". So I'd read UNEP being the project managers/facilitators, DOE as doing the spade work.